# why react does not run .map function?

Tags: javascript, react-native

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios'


//servislere bağlanabilmek için class haline getireceğiz
class Liste extends Component {
    state = {data: [] };
    UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
        console.log('componentWillMount');
        axios.get('https://reqres.in/api/users')
        .then(response => this.setState({ data: response.data}));
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('componentDidMount');
    }

    renderData() {
        return this.state.data.map( responseData => 
            <Text> {responseData.title} </Text>    
    );
    }

    render() {
        console.log('gelen data', this.state);
        console.log('render');
        return (
            <View style={{marginTop: 5}}>
                {this.renderData()}
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default Liste;
```

this is my Liste.js component script. i have an error that tell me **"this.state.data.map is not a function"**. what should i do? what is wrong with me?

Comment: `this` refers to the scope of `renderData`. `return state.data.map(...)` should work

Comment: What is the `response.data` in this line `.then(response => this.setState({ data: response.data}))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT :

As correctly pointed by @Bergi, we don't really need to `bind` the the `renderData` function, as the `state` is correctly available to the method. I took the liberty as created a fiddle to check the issues, and it is indeed with the `response` of the API call.

`response.data` returns an `object` but `response.data.data` is an `Array`. It is corrected in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kanithetoadsage/3q0L5h72/)

```
UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
   console.log('componentWillMount');
   axios.get('https://reqres.in/api/users')
    .then(response => {  
         this.setState({ data: response.data.data})
     });
}
```

---

<s>You need to `bind` the `renderData`  to the correct lexical scope for react to be able to refer to your component's state defined within.</s>  Also, I'd recommend checking your `response.data` returned from the API call before setting the state.

Other option is to use arrow function `renderData = () => {...}` but it has a drawback that every instance of your component will get its own copy of this function, thereby increasing its memory footprint.

You can do the following:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios'


//servislere bağlanabilmek için class haline getireceğiz
class Liste extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {data: [] };
      this.renderData = this.renderData.bind(this);
    }
    
    UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
        console.log('componentWillMount');
        axios.get('https://reqres.in/api/users')
        .then(response => { 
            if(response && Array.isArray(response.data)) {
               this.setState({ data: response.data})
            } else {
              // handle the type mismatch here
            }
         });
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('componentDidMount');
    }

    renderData() {
        return this.state.data.map( responseData => 
            <Text> {responseData.title} </Text>    
        );
    }

    render() {
        console.log('gelen data', this.state);
        console.log('render');
        return (
            <View style={{marginTop: 5}}>
                {this.renderData()}
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default Liste;
```

Comment: What `renderMap` and `renderMethod` are you talking about?

Comment: Also, no, the problem is not caused by the method not being bound to `this`. In that case the error message would have been something like "*cannot access `.state` on `undefined` (`this`)*" or "*cannot access `.data` on `undefined` (`this.state`)*"

Comment: @Bergi my bad regarding the `renderMap`. Also, I think issue is similar to binding of `state` to the class' instance, which maybe is leading to `data` being undefined.

Comment: No, `state` and `renderData` need not be bound to the instance. They're readily available in the `render` method, which is called on the instance just fine. The problem is that `state.data` is not an array and therefore doesn't have a `map` method, as suggested by @HanchenJiang in the question comments.

Comment: @Bergi I see your point. There's an API call being made in componentWillMount, which may not be returning Array type `data`. I updated the answer to check for the same. Thanks for the keen eye!

Comment: You might better want to post that as a second answer. As it stands, "*You need to bind the renderData  to the correct lexical scope for react to be able to refer to your component's state defined within.*" is still just wrong.

Comment: Thank you man. I see that the key point is only  "response.data returns an object but response.data.data is an Array"